# from snowflake.snowpark import Session - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake' Airflow bash operator

Tags: python, airflow, virtual, virtual-environment

I am executing a python script in different virtual environment, from airflow using bashoperator. This python code is running fine when executed individually in the virtual environment, but if I am executing it from Airflow using below bash command its throwing me error: *from snowflake.snowpark import Session -  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake'.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.providers.airbyte.operators.airbyte import AirbyteTriggerSyncOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

with DAG(dag_id='archive_chbe_s3',
    default_args={'owner': 'airflow'},
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    start_date=days_ago(1)
) as dag:
    
    task_get_last_file_read=BashOperator(
        task_id = "task_get_last_file_read",
        bash_command = "cd /home/avi/miniconda3/envs/avi_snowpark && source activate avi_snowpark && python get_max_date_by_table.py;"
                    )



    task_get_last_file_read
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `ExternalPythonOperator`?

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#externalpythonoperator

You can reference a virtual environment. It could be that Bash isn't keeping the virtual environment activated when it executes the final command. Either way the best practice is to use this operator and should be much easier.

Hope this helps!